# please help me i can't read or write from or to server-client and i have no clue why?

Tags: java

please help me i can't read or write from or to server-client and i have no clue why?

server app

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9000);

    while(true){
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("connected to client "+s.getInetAddress().getHostName());

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);

        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String msgin;
        while((msgin=in.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(msgin);
        }

        String msgout  = stdin.readLine();
        out.println("Server: "+msgout);

    }
}
```

client app

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
            Socket s =new Socket("localhost",9000);

            while(true){
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);

            BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String msgin;
            while((msgin=in.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(msgin);
            }

            String msgout  = stdin.readLine();
            out.println("Client: "+msgout);
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your app? Do you get any errors?

Comment: it says that server and client are connected but when i try to send messages it doesn't sent or receive any thing

Answer (score 2):

Both sides read in data from the Socket until it's closed. That's not happening, so both sides wait endlesly for data from the other side, a classical deadlock situation.

Comment: thanks for your answer.i closed the sockets,but still not working

Comment: With Sockets being closed you can't send or receive anything anymore over it.